# How to refer to the disabled option from inside a create event in jQuery UI?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-droppable

How do I refer to the disabled option from inside a create event?

The code below works, but I would like to do it slightly cleaner and shorter by not referring to `$(this)`, but instead to the "event" and "ui" parameters. I lack the knowledge to understand or know how to work with these parameters.

```
$(".myDroppables").droppable({
    create: function (event, ui) {
        //If class is full then set option disabled to true.
        if ($(this).hasClass('full'))
            $(this).droppable("option", "disabled", true);
    }
});
```

I imagine that it would look something like this:

```
$(".myDroppables").droppable({
    create: function (event, ui) {
        if ($(this).hasClass('full'))
            this.disabled = true;
    }
});
```

How do I do it?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot make sense of your question. What's wrong with using `this`? What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: What does event and ui mean inside the create event? I would like to know if I could use them instead of this. For example the object that is dragged, has that something to do with the ui? If so It would be useful for other functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback arguments are documented in the droppable widget's [overview](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/):

> All callbacks receive two arguments: The original browser event and a
>   prepared `ui` object:
>
> - `ui.draggable` - current draggable element, a jQuery object.
> - `ui.helper` - current draggable helper, a jQuery object.
> - `ui.position` - current position of the draggable helper `{ top: ,
>     left: }`
> - `ui.offset` - current absolute position of the draggable helper `{
>     top: , left: }`

That said, the `ui` argument passed to a [dropcreate](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#event-create) callback *won't expose any of these properties* ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gjRkF/)), probably because it's too early in the widget's lifecycle for them to have any meaning.

In your particular case, you're more or less forced to use `this` in order to apply the [disabled](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#option-disabled) option. However, you can cache the return value of `$(this)` to slightly improve performance:

```
$(".myDroppables").droppable({
    create: function(event, ui) {
        var $this = $(this);
        // If class is full then set option disabled to true.
        if ($this.hasClass("full")) {
            $this.droppable("option", "disabled", true);
        }
    }
});
```